# Connecting to DB in a function via including class (with the connection part)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php file in which I have a function that runs (besides other stuff) a select query. Now before this select query can take place I of course need to connect to the db first. For this, I am currently trying to include the following `connectdb.php` inside of the function right before the select query, but it fails/doesn't connect to the db. 
The content of the `connectdb.php`:

```
<?php  

require_once 'configdb.php'; // contains my database credentials

//Connect To Database

class connectdb
{
public function __construct($dsn, $user, $pw){
$this->pdo = $pdo;
if (!@$this->connect($dsn, $user, $pw)){
   echo "Failed.";
} else {
   echo "Successful.";
}
}

public function connect($dsn, $user, $pw){
    try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pw);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    $e->getMessage();
    }
}
}

$connect = new connectdb($dsn, $user, $pw);
$connect->connect($dsn, $user, $pw);

?>
```

The error, which relates to the following select query that obviously hasn't been able to get a connection to the db, is:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/xxx/html/xxx/index.php on line 753

I don't know where to find the mistake in the `connectdb.php` - already watched php videos about it and tried to adopt the code for my needs, but still, it errors. I also tried the following (doesn't work either):

```
<?php
require_once 'configdb.php';

class connectdb
{
public function __construct($dsn, $user, $pw){
try {
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pw);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    $e->getMessage();
    }
}
}

$connect = new connectdb($dsn, $user, $pw);
?>
```

EDIT - code that works now -: What I currently use and what solves the problem displayed above. `The database.php`:

```
<?php
//Class, which includes the connection function along other query functions

class Database{

// variables DB_HOSt, DB_USER etc. have been defined in an external file
private $host = DB_HOST;
private $user = DB_USER;
private $pass = DB_PASS;
private $dbname = DB_NAME;

private $dbh;
private $error;

public function __construct(){
    // Set DSN
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname . ';charset=utf8';
    // Set options
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT    => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE       => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'
    );
    // Create a new PDO instanace
    try{
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
    }
    // Catch any errors
    catch(PDOException $e){
        $this->error = $e->getMessage();
    }
 }

public function query($query){
$this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
}

public function bind($param, $value, $type = null){
if (is_null($type)) {
switch (true) {
case is_int($value):
  $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
  break;
case is_bool($value):
  $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
  break;
case is_null($value):
  $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
  break;
default:
  $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
}
}
$this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
}

public function execute(){
return $this->stmt->execute();
}

public function resultset(){
$this->execute();
return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
(...)
}
?>
```

And the `index.php` file with the query:

```
require_once ('../configdb.php');

require_once ('../database.php');


$database = new Database();

$selectsubjectsquery = "SELECT faecher.fach, klassen.klasse_id FROM faecher
LEFT JOIN
lehrer_faecher
ON
faecher.fach_id = lehrer_faecher.fach_id
LEFT JOIN
klassen
ON
lehrer_faecher.klasse_id = klassen.klasse_id
WHERE
lehrer_id = :lehrer AND lehrer_faecher.fach_id != :fach AND     lehrer_faecher.fach_id != '11'";

$database->query ($selectsubjectsquery);

$database->bind(':lehrer', $lehrer);
$database->bind(':fach', $fach);

$teachersubjects = $database->resultset();
```

Comment: What values are you passing into the constructor for connectdb?

Comment: Hi Drumbeg, I pass the database credentials `$dsn` (including host name and database name), `$user` (user name) and `$pw` (password). These are given by `configdb.php` by the code line `require_once 'configdb.php';`

Comment: Where are you calling `prepare()`?  Also, your `$pdo` variable is *only* accessible inside your `connect()` (or `__construct()`) function.  You want to set `$this->pdo` (or similar) instead, so you can access that variable outside of those functions.

Comment: Hi @ Rocket Hazmat, thanks for your answer, I have updated the post above with the part of the php file that includes the `prepare()`. I have included now: `$this -> pdo = $pdo` in the `__construct()` function but it still gives me _failed_ as a response when I try to call the `connectdb.php`. I know I'm still quite a beginner and I guess it's just about the `$this -> ...`part but it's extremely hard to find a video or a info page about it that explains where and how to put it into the functions above :/. I would be really grateful here for more information! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why the **@** symbol in **!@$this->connect($dsn, $user, $pw)**???

Comment: Hey Sakil, I followed the steps by a php class video and it included the "@". It still fails when I delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I will update the answer above - I have dont some things wrong concerning the usage of the connection function in the class and fixed it now.